# Is there a Java 1.7 JRE for 32-bit OS X?

Tags: java, macos

I'm looking for a 1.7 JRE which I can distribute with my Java application on OS X.  Oracle only offers a 64-bit version of the JRE for OS X, which means that I cannot support older 32-bit Macs.  Is there a 32-bit version somewhere?

Comment: I think the answer is no.  Do you have to use Java 7?  There is a 32 bit Java 6 available.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky: Afraid so - I'm using a third-party library that requires Java 7.  Out of curiosity, is the Java 6 JRE you mention the one supplied by Apple?  Or is it something I could distribute with my Java application like I do with Windows?

Comment: Versions of OS X (10.6 and earlier) which support 32-bit Macs don't support JDK 7.  So no.

Comment: @Mark Yes it was distributed by Apple.  Doesn't help if you need Java 7 though.  (Which is a reasonable requirement given JDK 6 has reached end of life.)

Comment: You might have to reconsider that third party library though.  Read "Why is Java 7 available only for Mac OS X 10.7.3 and above?" from http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml#java%20available

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there isn't. At least the only definitive thing I could find was [this](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp#mac):

> Mac OS X System Requirements
>
> Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion) or later.*
>   Administrator privileges for installation 64-bit browser Note that
>   installing Java on a Mac is performed on a system wide basis, for all
>   users, and administrator privileges are required. You cannot install
>   Java on a single-user basis.
>
> A 64-bit browser (Safari, Firefox or Chrome, for example) is required
>   to run Oracle Java on Mac OS X. 32-bit browsers do not support Java 7
>   and later versions on the Mac platform.
>
> - Users with Mac OS X versions 10.6 and below should go to Software Update under the Apple menu to look for updates.

And there isn't anything for 32-bit Mac OS X on [Oracle JDK8 download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) either.

It safe to assume that there is no Java 7 or newer for 32-bit Mac.